# distinct record by with oldest date

Tags: sql, date, distinct

Ok i have 2 tables 
they have matching customer id fields 
customer has `cust_id` as a primary field and orders has many `cust_Ids`

I want to display the first order record (earlist dated) for each customer id

```
Select customer.*, orders.*
from customer , orders
where orders.date = (select max(orders.date) from orders
where customer.customer-id = orders.customer-id)
```

This query combines the tables but i have multiple entries for each customer id and I only want the oldest date entry for each customer-id

How do I just get the oldest date record for each customer

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this using an outer apply.  That would look something like this:

`select c.*, o.* 
from customer c
outer apply (
    select top 1 * 
    from orders o 
    where o.Customer-ID = c.Customer-ID
    order by o.Date asc
    ) o`